# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')when trying to delete the note

Tags: reactjs, redux

I started to learn redux and I have a problem with the code. I would like to delete the note, but when the function executes, I get such an error

" Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')
at rootReducer"

Can someone solve it?

**Action**

```
export const deleteNote = (id) => {
  return {
    type: 'DELETE_NOTE',
    payload: {
      id,
    },
  }
}
```

**Reducers**

```
const initialState = {
  notes: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
      content: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
      content: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
      content: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      NoteType: 'note',
    },
  ],
}
const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'DELETE_NOTE':
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.payload.id]: state.notes.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload.id),
      }

    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default rootReducer
```

**Component**

```
const StyledDiv_3 = styled.div`
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 4px solid rgb(80, 208, 228);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
`

class Note extends Component {
  state = {
    redirect: false,
  }

  render() {
    const { title, content, id, deleteNote } = this.props
    const { redirect } = this.state
    return (
      <StyledDiv_3>
        <DeleteNote onClick={() => deleteNote(id)}>delete</DeleteNote>
        <NoteTitle>{id}</NoteTitle>
        <NoteContentContainer>
          <NoteContent>{content}</NoteContent>
        </NoteContentContainer>
      </StyledDiv_3>
    )
  }
}
Note.protoTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  content: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  postType: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}
Note.defaultProps = {
  postType: 'posts',
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  deleteNote: (id) => dispatch(deleteNoteAction(id)),
})

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Note)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please if you post a bigger chunk of code format it first, as it was incredibly difficult to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your return statement in the reducer should look like this:

```
return {
    ...state, 
    notes: state.notes.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload.id) 
}
```